# How to get System Language?

Tags: java, android, locale

In application supporting multiple languages using `Locale.setDefault(newLocale);` we are changing the language but there is no way to change language to device default language. What is the best way to find device default language in settings programatically.

Comment: Call `Locale.getDefault()`, and save the result.

Comment: After setting new locale it will return the last locale we set so its not usefull, thanks

Comment: :: sigh :: Call `Locale.getDefault()` **before you call `Locale.setDefault()`**, and save the result.

Comment: No but if user changes the language in settings it will not work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this:

`Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();`

Answer (score 2):

In general, store user modifiable setting in a variable controlled by you, not Oracle.  I.e. never call `Locale.setDefault` when user changes your application's locale, but rather change a variable under your control.

There are overrides for each locale-dependent method that take `Locale` parameter.

That's where you should pass locale variable under your control.

This way, you can always consult `Locale.getDefault` for system settings.

Comment: thanks for your answer but its in context of android so Locale.setDefault is useful to me to set the new language in app

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```